# How to set the application menu language in Electron App?

Tags: electron

[my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8auGa.png)

My electron app's language is English, but my system's is Chinese.So I found the application menu will appear some Chinese.How could I fix this? Or How could I set the language in English.

`{
        label: 'Edit',
        submenu: [
            { role: 'undo' },
            { role: 'redo' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'cut' },
            { role: 'copy' },
            { role: 'paste' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'selectall' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            {
                label: 'Structure',
                submenu: [
                    { label: 'Balance Delimiter' },
                    { label: 'Re-Indent' },
                    { label: 'Shift Right', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+]' },
                    { label: 'Shift Left', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+[' },
                    { type: 'separator' },
                    { label: 'Move Line Up', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+[' },
                    { label: 'Move Line Down', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+]' },
                    { label: 'Comment/Uncomment', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+/' },
                    { label: 'Add Documentation', accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Alt+/' },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }`

Comment: I fount when I remove the role 'copy'.the Chinese will disappear.BTW, the Chinese means "Begin Dictation"

Comment: I have a reverse problem: my application and system are in Spanish language but the menu items without the `label` property are displayed in English.